# WSE 3.0 encrypt signature c#

Tags: c#, xml, encryption, soap, digital-signature

I work with a  soap objects in a C# project

I need to send a secure request, signed and encrypted, now I  have this code

```
public void request() {
        Uri destinationUri = new Uri("SomePath");

        EndpointReference destination = new EndpointReference(destinationUri);
        SoapSender sender = new SoapSender(destination);

        SoapEnvelope envelope = new SoapEnvelope();
        envelope.Context.Addressing.Action = new Action("http://www.some\blabla");                        

        XmlElement xe = envelope.CreateElement("demo");
        envelope.Body.AppendChild(xe);


        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\certi.p12", "blabla", X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet);

        X509SecurityToken myToken = new X509SecurityToken(cert);           

        MessageSignature sig = new MessageSignature(myToken);
        sig.SignatureOptions = SignatureOptions.IncludeTimestamp | SignatureOptions.IncludeSoapBody;

        EncryptedData myEncData = new EncryptedData(myToken); 

        envelope.Context.Security.Elements.Add(sig);

        envelope.Context.Security.Elements.Add(myEncData);

        try
        {
            sender.Send(envelope);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
  }
```

And works, but it encrypts only body not the **signature**

I must also encrypt the signature

currently it produces this request

```
<soap:Envelope>
    <soap:Header>
        <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-d8175ff3-5253-447e-b2cb-59766874db62">
                <wsu:Created>2015-09-13T05:09:12Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2015-09-13T05:14:12Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            </Signature>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <xenc:EncryptedData>
        </xenc:EncryptedData>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: No, **you don't**. You want to encrypt first, sign later. Read about padding and plaintext oracle attacks.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes accurate, but a requirement needed first sign and then encrypt the signature, is possible with WSE?

Comment: "Also, as described in XML Encryption, we note that the combination of signing and encryption over a common data item may introduce some cryptographic vulnerability. For example, encrypting digitally signed data, while leaving the digital signature in the clear, may allow plain text guessing attacks. Care should be taken by application designers not to introduce such vulnerabilities." Well, that sounds like it is *possible* for sure :) The link to the XML plaintext vulnerabilities is from a German university paper which I mailed my own XML padding oracle right after publishing their paper :)